# How to rewrite Rejected-By-Urlscan in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net, rewrite

I'm migrating an ASP.NET app from IIS6 to IIS7 and in doing this I'm also porting my rewrite settings from Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to using IIS rewriting.

In have some problems with "Rejected-By-Urlscan" errors (urls like `/åäö.html` should be redirected to my 404 page).

In Intelligencia.UrlRewriter this worked:

```
<rewrite url="^~/Rejected-By-UrlScan" to="~/sidan-finns-inte.html"/>
```

I ported this to:

```
  <rule name="Rejected-By-UrlScan">
    <match url="^Rejected-By-UrlScan" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/sidan-finns-inte.html" />
  </rule>
```

But I keep gettings IIS internal 404 error instead of my 404 error (sidan-finns-inte.html).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding:

```
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

In Web.Config